# Oracle Report 2.5 ordering rows and columns with Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g, oraclereports

I work in a company that was working on an Oracle 8i Database along with Oracle Developer 2000 (Forms 4.5 & Reports 2.5). Recently, We are trying to update the Database to 10g. Everything seems to be working smoothly, but in the report the order of the rows are not ordered correctly. Also, the columns keeps switching places each time a report is requested. They work perfectly fine on the old database. Forgot to mention that we upgraded using the dump tool. We dumped the entire database from the old to the new database.

Anyone have an idea how to solve this problem.

Note: We don't have the source of either the forms or the reports. We only have the compiled modules.

Any help would really be appreciated

Comment: Do you know at least something about the query the report is running?

Comment: I am not sure whether they're one of the views created or not, but why would one of them change during export?

Comment: Have you tried to include an ORDER BY clause in the view?

Comment: Well, I am trying to find a way to know the view that the report is running. Since I don't have to source module, I am trying to use the management tools to know which view its running, but I am not really good at using the DB management tools. If you could share with me some tutorials or video. I would really appreciate it.